# Not able to get a brother printer working

Tags: drivers, printing, brother

I think I have successfully been able to finally set the printer up. I can ping it and I do receive the response. weird how a mainstream OS like ubuntu can make printer setup this insanely difficult.

[image]

Anyhow, I cannot still get it to print anything. All my jobs go to pending state with error message `Stopped - cfFilterChain: pdftopdf (PID 4412) exited with no errors.` I could print just fine using my Android phone. It was no more complex than 3 clicks and bam the printer was set up

How can I get the printer to start printing? Please let me know whatever supplemental information need to help me get this working. Thank in advance :)